# Environmet variables set to root container user instead of postgres container user by default

Tags: docker, environment-variables

Everytime I start a new instance of a container from the [PostgreSQL docker hub's official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), the environment variables are defined and exported in the root user of the shell created by the container instead of being defined and export in the postgres user.

For example, when I input the `env` command through root user:

```
PWD=/
HOME=/root
LANG=en_US.utf8
GOSU_VERSION=1.14
PG_MAJOR=15
PG_VERSION=15.1-1.pgdg110+1
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Using the same command but through postgres user:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PWD=/var/lib/postgresql/data
LOGNAME=postgres
HOME=/var/lib/postgresql
TERM=xterm
USER=postgres
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
MAIL=/var/mail/postgres
OLDPWD=/var/lib/postgresql/data/base
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Why is this happening? I've read the documentation but I found nothing. Is there a way to set these variables in postgres user instead of root by default?

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?  I would normally expect the `postgres` image to run only a PostgreSQL server, and not a shell.  Since the container only runs a single process there's only effectively a single user.  How (and why) are you running these `env` commands?

Comment: You normally interact with the postgres container as `root`, and you supply `-U postgres` to commands that need it (`psql -U postgres ...` or `createdb -U postgres ...`, etc). There's generally no need to be running a shell as the `postgres` user.